# Should auto unboxing of numbers in java use Number.xxxValue() rather than cast to XXX.xxxValue()?

Tags: java

Examples work best, imagine Object is a Byte and we attempt to cast it to a long...

Currently the byte code looks a bit like this

```
   Byte b = Byte.valueOf(1);
   Object source = b;
   Long long = (Long) source;     // fails CCE because a Byte is not a Long
   long value = long.longValue();
```

Wouldnt a cast to Number be better ?

```
  Byte b = Byte.valueOf(1);
   Number number = (Number) b;     // f
   long value = number.longValue();
```

The real problem is of course we have reduce the possibility for ClassCastExceptions, is that a bad thing ?

Answer (score 2):

Why cast at all? `Byte`s have the [`longValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#longValue%28%29) method as well.

```
Byte b = Byte.valueOf(1);
long value = b.longValue();
```

Or better yet:

```
byte b = 1;
long value = (long) b;
```

Comment: everythig you say is true, but when unboxing the compiler inserts a cast. sorry if i failed to make this clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care what the original type is, I would just cast to a Number as you have done.

Comment: Unboxing will only occur when no casting is required. Can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 0):

From smaller ints to bigger ones, you don't need casting. It is called *promotion* and works by assignment:

```
    byte b = (byte) 200;
    long l = b;
    Long ll = l;
```

For Byte-byte and long-Long conversion you can use autoboxing.

Comment: First byte -> long is not a cast, by a promotion as you say. Im talking about casts in my q.

Comment: You cast from parent class to child. Since there is no child-parent relationship between byte and long, you can't cast one into the other.